# How to jump to particular page by autoscrolling in pdf.js using react?

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js

I am displaying the whole PDF in a single canvas using mozilla PDF.js.
However, I need the PDF to jump to a specific page on display, based on a preexisting page number state variable.
I looked at [the following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807055/jump-to-page-in-pdf-js-with-javascript), however I'm seeing that PDFViewerApplication is not defined in the PDF object.
Kindly guide me.

Comment: Do you have a render function? Something that looks like this: `await pdfjsLib.getDocument(`${url}`).promise.then((pdfDoc_) => {})`

Comment: Yes,I have renderFunction like PDFJS.getDocument({data:pdfData})

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.